# Get the value of selected checkboxes in an array - WPF, MVVC, c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox

Hi I am am working on an application that has MVVC framework.

On my view I have 23 checkboxes each with a different text.

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding isA}">A</CheckBox>
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding isB}">B</CheckBox>
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding isC}">C</CheckBox>
```

and so on.

in viewmodal I have the following....

```
public string isA
    {
        get { return _isA; }
        set
        {
            _isA= value.ToString();
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private string _isA;
```

How do I get all the selected checkboxes text as an array?

Answer (score 0):

Start by defining a model class

```
public class ListModel
 {
     public string Data { get; set; }
     public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
 }
```

Then Bind the list of this model to the Listview's ItemsSource

```
List<ListModel> data = new List<ListModel>();
```

modify the binding of your check box to

```
 <CheckBox Content="{Binding Data}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay"/>
```

then when you need to retrieve you may execute the following linq to get all selected strings

```
IEnumerable<String> selectedData = data.Where(d => d.IsSelected).Select(d => d.Data);
```

now you'll have all the data which is selected in the UI in the field selectedData